# Spring Security Programmatic authorization

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm adding admin/test users to my Spring Boot Application with Spring Security / JPA based authentication via an ApplicationRunner.

Before that I had a data.sql file, but I need to support several databases, so I was looking for a portable solution.

I have a Spring Data JPA Repository for users and simply added my users like so:

```
@Component
public class MyRunner implements ApplicationRunner {
private UserRepository userRepository;

@Autowired
public MyRunner(UserRepository userRepository) {
  this.userRepository = userRepository;
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see org.springframework.boot.ApplicationRunner#run(org.springframework.boot.ApplicationArguments)
 */
@Override
public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
    User admin = new User("admin", "admin", Roles.ROLE_ADMIN);
    userRepository.saveAndFlush(admin);
}
```

}

That worked fine. But I activated Spring global method security, to secure the UserRepository, which is also exposed via REST:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
@Override
<S extends User> S save(S user);
```

But then adding users failed, since I wasn't authorized. I tried this hack:

```
@Override
public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
    User admin = new User("admin", "admin", Roles.ROLE_ADMIN);
    Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(admin, null,
      AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ROLE_ADMIN"));
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
    userRepository.saveAndFlush(admin);

    SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
}
```

The user gets added, but authentication in the web app itself is now thoroughly broken...

I only get **AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException**

```
o.s.b.a.audit.listener.AuditListener     : AuditEvent [timestamp=Mon Dec 05 19:12:10 CET 2016, principal=<unknown>, type=AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE, data={type=org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException, message=An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm simply using a work-around:

I've deactivated Method Security and I simply put all Spring Data Endpoints behind a /data/-prefixed route. Then I can use Spring Security with all the different modifying HTTP Methods (POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE).

Comment: Although honestly, I'm not very happy with this "solution". This creates a ton of new antMatchers with all the exceptions etc.